# Reason of failing on first iteration of CMUSphinx Baum Welch training

Tags: machine-learning, speech-recognition, cmusphinx

I am trying to build a new acoustic model, I used a speech synthesizer to train it, the total estimate hours of training files is:
0.0389416666666667
, But I keep getting an error after Baum Welch training, this the error I'm getting:

`Sphinxtrain path: /usr/local/lib/sphinxtrain
Sphinxtrain binaries path: /usr/local/libexec/sphinxtrain
Running the training
MODULE: 000 Computing feature from audio files
Extracting features from  segments starting at  (part 1 of 1) 
Extracting features from  segments starting at  (part 1 of 1) 
Feature extraction is done
MODULE: 00 verify training files
    Phase 1: Checking to see if the dict and filler dict agrees with the 
phonelist file.
        Found 81 words using 49 phones
    Phase 2: Checking to make sure there are not duplicate entries in 
the dictionary
    Phase 3: Check general format for the fileids file; utterance length 
(must be positive); files exist
    Phase 4: Checking number of lines in the transcript file should 
match lines in fileids file
    Phase 5: Determine amount of training data, see if n_tied_states 
seems reasonable.
        Estimated Total Hours Training: 0.0389416666666667
        This is a small amount of data, no comment at this time
    Phase 6: Checking that all the words in the transcript are in the 
dictionary
        Words in dictionary: 78
        Words in filler dictionary: 3
    Phase 7: Checking that all the phones in the transcript are in the 
phonelist, and all phones in the phonelist appear at least once
MODULE: 0000 train grapheme-to-phoneme model
Skipped (set $CFG_G2P_MODEL = 'yes' to enable)
MODULE: 01 Train LDA transformation
Skipped for multistream setup, see CFG_NUM_STREAMS configuration
LDA/MLLT only has sense for single stream features
Skipping LDA training
MODULE: 02 Train MLLT transformation
Skipped for multistream setup, see CFG_NUM_STREAMS configuration
LDA/MLLT only has sense for single stream features
Skipping MLLT training
MODULE: 05 Vector Quantization
ERROR: This step had 2 ERROR messages and 0 WARNING messages.  Please 
check the log file for details.
MODULE: 10 Training Context Independent models for forced alignment and 
VTLN
Skipped:  $ST::CFG_FORCEDALIGN set to 'no' in sphinx_train.cfg
Skipped:  $ST::CFG_VTLN set to 'no' in sphinx_train.cfg
MODULE: 11 Force-aligning transcripts
Skipped:  $ST::CFG_FORCEDALIGN set to 'no' in sphinx_train.cfg
MODULE: 12 Force-aligning data for VTLN
Skipped:  $ST::CFG_VTLN set to 'no' in sphinx_train.cfg
MODULE: 20 Training Context Independent models
    Phase 1: Cleaning up directories:
    accumulator...logs...qmanager...models...
    Phase 2: Flat initialize
    Phase 3: Forward-Backward
        Baum welch starting for 256 Gaussian(s), iteration: 1 (1 of 1)
        0% 20% 30% 60% 90% 100% 
ERROR: This step had 86 ERROR messages and 0 WARNING messages.  Please 
check the log file for details.
ERROR: Training failed in iteration 1`

I have also set the CFG_CD_TRAIN to 'no' since i have a small training data.

Edit: 
I checked the log file, here is a pastebin of the log:
http://pastebin.com/YBSqfxYW

Comment: It tells you: please check log file for details.

Comment: Well, here is the log:
http://pastebin.com/YBSqfxYW

Comment: Log says you do not have enough data for training

Comment: So is there a way of training with small amount of data? Cause I've seen some people they train a "Numbers" model which I think it has few training data.

Comment: No, data requirements are listed in tutorial, you can't train with less than that. And, it seems you are using older sphinxtrain. Latest sphinxtrain will enforce data requirements.

Comment: So the minimum data that is required has to be 5 hours right?

Comment: Correct, there is no need to ask to confirm the tutorial

Comment: Thank you sir for your help and your time.